# How to remove icon border in Android 12

Tags: android, android-recents, adaptive-icon

Assuming this is my app icon
[image]

It works fine in Android 11 (and below)
[image]

but when I install the app in Android 12, there is a white border around the icon in the splash screen (also a black border around the top app icon.)
[image]

Is there any way I can remove those borders?
below is my splash code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorBlack"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/notice"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Also this line in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:roundIcon="@drawable/notice"
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems a misusage in your terminology *splash screen*. It should be called [*Recents screen*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/recents) in the screen shots.

So this is not a problem about [Splash screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen). This should be a problem about a launcher icon using [Adaptive icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive).

By default, in template projects on Android Studio, the launcher icons in the Manifest are:

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

And both of mipmaps are:

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Lastly, both of these `ic_launcher_foreground` and `ic_launcher_background` are vector drawables. (note that you can also use @color instead of a vector drawable)

As you can notice, `layer-list` or bitmap is not used. You can use an [Adaptive icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) on API-26+.